# Trying to make an AI in Java

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I am currently trying to learn how to program AI in Java (although I would be willing to learn in C#, C++, Javascript, etc). I have been watching Code Bullet videos on YouTube, and it got me itching to make a basic AI using a genetic algorithm (to start with). However, I have NO idea where to start, how to proceed, or even what program to use, or if I need any libraries. I am fairly well educated in Java mostly, so that is why I chose it for my AI, however, if other languages are better for AI, I'm ready to learn and experiment. I don't currently have any ideas in mind for the AI (if I needed one, I would probably start off with creating a clone of the Worlds Hardest Game program, although I hope that the knowledge I learn allows me to apply said knowledge to any program). Any ideas?

Additionally, if anyone has any knowledge on neural networks and machine learning combined with machine vision and other possible inputs, please let me know!

Comment: Buy a book, learn the mathematics/algorithms, implement those in whatever programming language. That's what I did. [Here's](https://www.pearson.com/uk/educators/higher-education-educators/program/Negnevitsky-Artificial-Intelligence-A-Guide-to-Intelligent-Systems-3rd-Edition/PGM995577.html?tab=overview) the book I started with and [that's](https://www.python.org/) the language I've used.

Comment: Sounds like a fun challenge! The secret to getting started is starting. Pick a problem and try something. Depending on the problem and your approach, there may be well known techniques and ready built libraries, or you may be on your own. This question is too broad for this site though, Stackoverflow is best for concrete programming problems, not general project advice.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As u mention that you will learn any programming language to build an AI. Then start with Python programming. Python has a lot of powerful libraries that will make stuff easy. I am also fresher but find Python is relatively easy to learn and apply for creating a Machine Learning. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make sure to check it out. Doing game design to make a gauntlet for the AI may be difficult on Python, however, it is a starting point, and I shall learn! Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you, bro, for game development Python is still working. C# is good to start with game development using Unity.